# Focussing the combobox is difficult in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, combobox, focus

We have a WPF application where we have extended the `Combobox` Class. Now `ComboBox` focus gets activated only when we mouse hover the triangle sign on the `ComboBox`. It might be just a property change but I am new to WPF so it is difficult for me to find.

Comment: How about you post the XAML?

Comment: Actually, focussing the `ComboBox` is easy in a WPF application: `comboBox.Focus()`. If you have extended the `ComboBox` class and 'broken' it, then maybe you should call your post 'Focussing custom `ComboBox` is difficult in WPF application'? Either way, how can anyone help you fix your broken code if you don't show it?